Auto-fix laravel code style using GitLab CI
I want to run Laravel Pint as part of my CI pipeline in Gitlab.
I try to install composer packages, then call pint to format code and finally commit changes.
Here is .gitlab-ci.yml file:
image: php:8.3.0-alpine3.17

stages:
  - Pint

Pint:
  stage: Pint
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env || true
    - php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - vendor/bin/pint
    - apk update && apk add git
    - git config --global user.email "gitlab-ci@example.com"
    - git config --global user.name "GitLab CI"
    - git add --all
    - git commit -m "PHP Linting (Pint)" || true

  except:
    - /^dependabot\/.*$/

  allow_failure: true



And it is the result of job :
Running with gitlab-runner 17.0.0~pre.88.g761ae5dd (761ae5dd)
  on green-2.saas-linux-small-amd64.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default ns46NMmJ, system ID: s_85d7af184313
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:07
Using Docker executor with image php:8.3.0-alpine3.17 ...
Pulling docker image php:8.3.0-alpine3.17 ...
Using docker image sha256:ac05df6e9686c557254bd7843bbb1164920bff492cb97cb450bc76867ea55a81 for php:8.3.0-alpine3.17 with digest php@sha256:af0809570027627bd16e89dea01fefcec427a1220dcaa494ee9d7afdfcfc2fcc ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-ns46nmmj-project-60415110-concurrent-0 via runner-ns46nmmj-s-l-s-amd64-1722426842-977ec945...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/majva/test/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 33e3c9ff as detached HEAD (ref is ci)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ git remote set-url origin "${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}"
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:09
Using docker image sha256:ac05df6e9686c557254bd7843bbb1164920bff492cb97cb450bc76867ea55a81 for php:8.3.0-alpine3.17 with digest php@sha256:af0809570027627bd16e89dea01fefcec427a1220dcaa494ee9d7afdfcfc2fcc ...
$ cp .env.example .env || true
$ php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Composer (version 2.7.7) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer
$ composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
$ vendor/bin/pint
  .✓......................✓.
  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── Laravel  
    FIXED   ................................... 26 files, 2 style issues fixed  
  ✓ app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php phpdoc_indent, braces_position, stat…  
  ✓ tests/Pest.php function_declaration, unary_operator_spaces, braces_positi…  
$ apk update && apk add git
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.17.9-10-g237185b0671 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main]
v3.17.9-10-g237185b0671 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community]
OK: 17832 distinct packages available
(1/3) Installing libexpat (2.6.2-r0)
(2/3) Installing pcre2 (10.42-r0)
(3/3) Installing git (2.38.5-r0)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r29.trigger
OK: 23 MiB in 38 packages
$ git config --global user.email "gitlab-ci@example.com"
$ git config --global user.name "GitLab CI"
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "PHP Linting (Pint)" || true
[detached HEAD a59d3c0] PHP Linting (Pint)
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded

As you can see it seems every thing is ok.
But in fact, the code on the repo has not changed.
Does anyone know where the problem is?
Are there other settings that I haven't done?

Are you missing a git push after your commit?

It doesn't work. It says that you are not on a git branch

Have you tried checking out a branch?
